# IF condition in a cell name search function

Tags: excel, search, if-statement

Okay so I'm stumped. I'm trying to create a function that will find any letter ("c" for example) in a specified column and grab the value in the cell next to it to add into a larger sum.

Example:

```
A1=3, B1=c, 
A2=4, B2=d, 
A3=1, B3=c
```

should return `4`

How would I achieve that in excel-like language?

Comment: is your input a file? what tool or language?

Comment: Do you mean in Excel?

Comment: Just so give a brief introduction in concepts. "if" isn't a function, a function is "doing something". It's also not a loop, a loop is "repeating something". it's a conditional, a statement "deciding what to do based on a condition".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want this in Excel, type the following function in C1

```
=IF(B1="c", A1, 0)
```

Drag the cell C1 to fill the column. i.e.

```
C2 will be =IF(B2="c", A2, 0)
C3 will be =IF(B3="c", A3, 0) etc.
```

Now use summation on column C.

[image]

Comment: why not [SUMIF](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx)?